# error when set multiple variable values from multiple select queries

Tags: php, mysql

How i can set multiple variable values from multiple select queries in php.
here is php code(trans.php)

```
<?php
include('config.inc');
$pname       = $_POST['pname'];
$usrname     = $_POST['usrname'];
$iname       = $_POST['iname'];
$udec        = $_POST['udec'];  
$usize       = $_POST['usize'];
$qty         = $_POST['qty'];   
$lname       = $_POST['lname']; 

$p_id = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `project_master` WHERE ( `Project_Code` = '" . $_POST['pname']  . "') "),0);
$user_id = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT `u_id` FROM `user` WHERE ( `user_name` = '" . $_POST['usrname']. "') "),0);
$i_id = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `item_master` WHERE ( `item_name`    = '" . $_POST['iname']  . "') "),0);
$unit_id = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `unit_mstr` WHERE( `Unit_Name`    = '" . $_POST['udec']   . "') "),0);
$loc_id = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `location_mstr` WHERE( `l_name`       = '" . $_POST['lname']  . "') "),0);
$sql= " INSERT INTO project_transaction_header(project_id, u_id, item_Id, unit_id,Size, Qty, location_id, Created_On, Created_By, Modified_on, Modified_By) VALUES ('$p_id','$user_id','$i_id',$unit_id','$item_size','$item_qty','$loc_id',now(),'‌​system',now(),'system');";
```

but i got the error

```
Notice: Undefined index: usrname in C:\xampp\htdocs\alogin\ptrans.php on line 14

Warning: mysql_result(): Unable to jump to row 0 on MySQL result index 6 

Notice: Undefined index: iname in ..\..\ptrans.php on line 15

Warning: mysql_result(): Unable to jump to row 0 on MySQL result index 7 

Notice: Undefined index: udec in ..\..\ptrans.php on line 16

Warning: mysql_result(): Unable to jump to row 0 on MySQL result index 8 

Notice: Undefined index: lname in ..\..\ptrans.php on line 17
```

i receive vaules from my html page via post method..

here is my HTML code where i call that PHP
Transition.html

```
<HTML>
<head>
</head>
  <body>
   <div id="loginAdmin" class="animate form" >
   <form class="cbp-mc-form" action="ptrans.php" id="trans" method="post" >
   <div class="cbp-mc-column">
   <p><label>Project Name:</label> <input name="pname"id="pname" type="text" autocomplete="off"></p>
   &nbsp&nbsp
   <p><label>User Name:</label> <input id="usrname" name="usrname"type="text" autocomplete="off"></p>
   &nbsp&nbsp
   <p><label>Itme Name:</label> <input id="iname" name="iname" type="text" autocomplete="off"></p>
   </div>
  <div class="cbp-mc-column">                                   
  <p><label>Unit Dec:</label> <input id="udec" name="udec" type="text" autocomplete="off"></p>
  &nbsp&nbsp
  <p><label>Size:</label> <input id="usize" name="usize" type="text" autocomplete="off"></p>
  &nbsp&nbsp
  <p><label>QTY:</label> <input id="qty" name="qty" type="text" autocomplete="off"></p>
    </div>
  <div class="cbp-mc-column">   
    <p><label>Location Name:</label> <input name="lname"  id="lname" type="text" autocomplete="off"></p>
     </div>
     <div style="margin-top: 530px;"class="cbp-mc-submit-wrap"><input class="cbp-mc-submit" type="submit" value="SUBMIT" />
<input class="cbp-mc-submit" type="reset"  name="reset" id="reset"  value="Reset" />
</div>                              
    </form>                      
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Please, please, please stop using mysql_query, mysql_result like ancient, deprecated and unstable methods.

Comment: There is no `usrname` mentioned in your first (dummy) code. Please post your real code.

Comment: @foozy sorry i am new in this and firstly i tried to create procedure but i am unable to call in php so i have to gone through the older methode.. plz help me if u know new methods to set multiple variable

Comment: @AndyG here is my code  this is where i catch variable   
$pname       = $_POST['pname'];
$usrname     = $_POST['usrname'];
$iname       = $_POST['iname'];
$udec        = $_POST['udec']; 
$usize       = $_POST['usize'];
$qty         = $_POST['qty']; 
$lname       = $_POST['lname'];(setting variable)insert
$sql= " INSERT INTO `project_transaction_header`(`project_id`, `u_id`, `item_Id`, `unit_id`,`Size`, `Qty`, `location_id`, `Created_On`, `Created_By`, `Modified_on`, `Modified_By`) VALUES ('$p_id','$user_id','$i_id',$unit_id','$item_size','$item_qty','$loc_id',now(),'system',now(),'system');";

Comment: use mysqli instead of mysql functions, if you are posting errors, post actual code, that caused them -  not dummy code

Comment: @Nfunchar Gosh, the question in your title now has nothing to do with the code and error messages in your post. Change the title at least, if you can.

Comment: @JTC now i put whole code help me

Comment: show `var_dump($_POST); exit;` in ptrans.php file after submiting form;

Answer (score 0):

User `var_dump($_POST);` to see actual name of variables. Usrname and other indexes are simply not defined in post array.

Use [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) functions in php not mysql, because they already are deprecated, and they are not to be used in the future versions of php.